# Sum of digits of numbers

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, number-theory

Let S be a function such that S(N) is the sum of digits of N. N belongs to natural numbers, and N < 10²³. N does not contain a zero digit in it. The numbers are in base 10.

Find the number of N that satisfies the equation:
S(N) = S(S(N))

Comment: Discussion of this question [on meta](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7324/69582)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> S(*N*) ≤ *N* with equality iff *N* ≤ 9, so the solutions are {*N* : S(*N*) ≤ 9 ∧ 0 ∉ digits(*N*)}. This set is {1, 2, …, 8, 9, 11, 12, …, 17, 18, 21, …}.

> Denote the concatenation operator by ∥. S(*N*) = *k* iff *N* can be uniquely expressed as 1 ∥ 1 + 1 + 1 ∥ 1 + … + 1 for some combination of operators with *k* 1s. There are 2<sup>*k* − 1</sup> ways to do this. So the cardinality of the set is 2<sup>0</sup> + … + 2<sup>8</sup> = 2<sup>9</sup> − 1 = 511.

Comment: But how many numbers satisfy the solution?

Comment: @I'mNobody I didn't realise that was the question. (The last sentence in the problem statement is not very clear.) I've counted them now in an edit.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $2^{k-1}$ ways?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Yes. Thank you. I've edited it.

Comment: Now that is correct.